# How to hide dynamic divs unless all divs have a certain class - algolia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algolia

I'm using a service called [Algolia](http://www.algolia.com) which works like a single-page search appliance.  When a user types in a term to search, Algolia automatically loads children divs inside a containing span with possible suggestions.  The children divs are loaded with the DOM but the contents of the children divs change based upon the user input.  The divs are changed with every keypress from an input field.

#### Records Found

If the resulting search has discovered valid records, then a child div would contain something like:

```
<span id="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0">    
    <div class="aa-dataset-1">
      <span class="aa-suggestions" style="display: block;">
        <div class="aa-suggestion">
          <div class="algolia-result">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col nopadding">
                    <span>Dynamic data has been added</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
</span>
```

In the example above, class "aa-dataset-1" is a containing div for suggestions.  The "-1" represents a dynamic div that Algolia will add.  This means that I could have a dynamic divs with classes ranging of "aa-dataset-1" to "aa-dataset-X".

#### No Records Found

When no results are returned from Algolia, the containing div ("aa-dataset-X") still is populated with content.  An example of a search that returns zero results are:

```
<div class="aa-dataset-1">
  <div class="algolia-empty">
    <span>No results were found with your current selection.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue that I is that divs with a class of "algolia-empty" still shows even if there is a child div with class "aa-suggestions".  The below images show an example of a single record found but still showing the divs with class "algolia-empty"

[image]

Showing the class "algolia-empty" will always show because Algolia has built their product that way.

#### Question

What I want to do is hide all child divs inside of "algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0" **unless every** child div has a class of "algolia-empty".  Remember this is a single-page application.

#### A working JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jandk4014/8vktn0cu/44/

### UPDATE

What should a successful result from the service look like?  Review the image below.

[image]

If you want to see it in action the look at the JSFiddle link above.

Comment: what should appear when not all child have the class `algolia-empty`?

Comment: can't you just add a CSS: `.algolia-empty{ display: none;}`   ?  or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: When a record(s) is found from the Algolia service the subsequent divs are populated and the data is shown.  I'll modify the question to show an example of this.

Comment: right, edit the question. I would suggest you to make it smaller. There's a lot of text to read, not everybody have enough time to stay at a single question reading, so you may lose potential helpers.

Comment: `Showing the class "algolia-empty" will always show because Algolia has built their product that way` --I'm a bit confused by this. What is the officially recommended way to use it? That doesn't make sense that an official response would include that in a successful search. Does the `.algolia-empty` div not have any content by default?

Comment: You are correct that `.algolia-empty` can be void of content.  If that was the case then the situation is when a search term (e.g. FooBar) returns zero results there wouldn't be a display message for the user.  This would be a bad UX interaction.

Comment: Yeah I'm not suggesting to leave it blank, I was just curious if this was the default behavior. I'm still surprised there's not an official way to handle this issue, seems like something that should be handled by default

Comment: I do believe that for a multi-index process this is the default behavior.  This [question](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/issues/79) was asked on Algolia's official github page.  They indicate that the solution was merged into a release but I can't find documentation on how to handle a multi-index situation.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the empty template can be set in a "global" fashion via Algolia.

```
//Search for BR6340-02-0.250 > Success
//Search for blah > Failure

var client = algoliasearch('9G2RUKPPGE', '8860a74c330efaf0119818fcdd800126');

const indices = [
  ['SPR', 'Spacers'],
  ['SWG_SPR', 'Swage Spacers'],
  ['FF_STDF', 'Female-Female Standoffs'],
  ['SWG_STDF', 'Swage Standoffs'],
  ['MF_STDF', 'Male-Female Standoffs'],
  ['BSM', 'Ball Stud Males'],
  ['BSF', 'Ball Stud Females'],
  ['CHF', 'Chassis Fasteners'],
  ['MM_STDF', 'Male-Male Standoff'],
  ['SPR_TRQ', 'Super Torq Swage Standoffs'],
  ['CPS_1', 'Captive Panel Screw - Type 1']
];

const sources = indices.map(function(indexKeyValue) {
  var index = client.initIndex(indexKeyValue[0]);

  return {
    // source would be edited with the custom source from the other question
    source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {
      hitsPerPage: 15,
    }),
    displayKey: 'code',
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(suggestion) {
        const markup = `
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 nopadding">
                  <img src="${suggestion.image}" alt="" class="algolia-thumb">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                          <span>${suggestion._highlightResult.code.value}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                          <span>Available Qty: ${suggestion.quantityAvailable.toLocaleString()}</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row hidden-xs">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                          <span>${suggestion.description}</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>`;

        return `<div class="algolia-result">${markup}</div>`;
      }
    }
  };
});

$('#aa-search-input').autocomplete({
    hint: true,
    debug: true,
    templates: {
         empty: `<div class="algolia-result"><span> No results were found with your current selection.</span></div>`
    }
  },
  sources
).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/' + suggestion.url
});
```

I've got a couple things going on here that are cool.

1. I am iterating over an array that holds the names of the indices that I want to query against.  This was able to dramatically cut down on the redundant code that I was going to write based off of Algolia's tutorials.
2. I discovered, in more research, that I could have a "default template" in the root autocomplete() function as an option.  With that default template it was as simple as adding an 'empty' option to it.  This option checks to see if all the datasets are empty, then in my case, display a simple div.

Credit to these authors for getting me to the solution.

- https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/blob/master/README.md#events - Showed me that there was an autocomplete:empty function
- https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/issues/102#issuecomment-236410594 - Discovered that you can add a default template to the root of an autocomplete.

A functioning fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jandk4014/rtkhw7o0/43/

Comment: When i pull this up on my computer, and type in a result which should produce a single value, i get a list of repeating items. is that whats intended to happen?

Comment: @ja-superior - If you're pulling up the JSFiddle above just make sure you choose a full part number.  'BR6340-02-0.250' will yield a lot of results.  They're not repeating as the last characters in the string represent a 'finish' in our world.  If you search for a term of 'BR6340-02-0.250-00' or 'BR6340-02-0.250-34' you'll see the single record.